# OFFSET OR LIMIT which is efficient in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I am going to make pagination in my webpage. I want to know that Which is Most Efficient

```
"SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10,10"
```

OR

```
"SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10"
```

Is there any difference, if Yes, which is more better and more efficient?

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The offset syntax is offered to be compatible with postgres. See [man](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) page

```
For compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL also supports the LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset syntax.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.
From [MySQL reference SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

A few examples

```
LIMIT 5                     // limit the result to the first 5 rows
LIMIT 10,5.               // limit the result to 5 rows, beginning with row 11
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10 // same meaning
```

I prefer to write the long version, it is ANSI standard and you avoid the pitfall to mistake the order of params.

LIMIT alone:

> With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> For compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL also supports the LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset syntax.